# CTE - use updated records with upsert statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, upsert, postgresql-9.6

I would like to use the `src` records within the following `INSERET ... ON CONFLICT` statement

```
WITH src AS (
  UPDATE t1 SET
    dt = current_timestamp
    WHERE id = 1
  RETURNING *),
pub AS (
  INSERT INTO p1 SELECT s.* FROM src s
    ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET
      -- ???
    RETURNING *)
SELECT row_to_json(pub.*)
  FROM pub;
```

... but I'm not aware how to do this without specifying every column for the `p1` update. Basically `t1` and `p1` are identically and the insert/update is more like a copy.

So the question, is there a nice way to update `p1` `ON CONFLICT` without specifying all the columns?

Answer (score 1):

In few words: syntactically it is impossible (at least in simple way).

There is the trick where you do not need to write pairs like `f1 = excluded.f1, f2 = excluded.f2` and so on, but only two copies of the same field list:

```
WITH src AS (
  UPDATE t1 SET
    dt = current_timestamp
    WHERE id = 1
  RETURNING *),
pub AS (
  INSERT INTO p1 SELECT s.* FROM src s
    ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET
      (f1,f2,f3...) = (select f1,f2,f3... from (select excluded.*) as e)
    RETURNING *)
SELECT row_to_json(pub.*)
  FROM pub;
```

[Example on dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=cb8d76dc603cc49ae4a2305992b6449a)

Comment: Thanks, but specifying all the column names is exactly the thing I try to avoid :) ... If it's not possible maybe I should stick with delete + insert on `p1`

Comment: @hooblei Internally PostgreSQL doing exactly same things when updating row: inserts the new one with updated values and deletes the old copy: [_"When an MVCC database needs to update an item of data, it will not overwrite the old data with new data, but instead marks the old data as obsolete and adds the newer version elsewhere. "_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control)

Comment: Yupp, just thought that maybe there is a nice clean option to do it this way

Comment: @hooblei Just remember about concurrency.